# Access Symbol(_latestValue) elements of an Observable Array

Tags: php, arrays, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

```
printerViewModel['printerChecked']["Symbol(_latestValue)"]
```

I have find value by this code but print undefined from this response, please see this image

[image]

I Need false from Symbol(_latestValue) by array elements or object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public way of getting an observable's value is to run the function. So in this case, you should be able to retrieve the `false` value by calling:

```js
printerViewModel.printerChecked()
```

The debugger indicates that this property key is a [`Symbol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol). That means you can't access it by using the string `"Symbol(...)"`.

Symbols are usually used to hide stuff from you, so it is supposed to be impossible to retrieve.

The only exception I can think of is if the property was set using `Symbol.for`. As you can see from this util knockout uses, this isn't the case:

```js
createSymbolOrString: function(identifier) {
  return canUseSymbols ? Symbol(identifier) : identifier;
}
```

<sub>Source: https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/2bec689a9a7fcaaed37e6abb9fdec648f86c4f81/src/utils.js#L513</sub>

---

Some basic snippets to help you understand symbols:

```js
const symbolFor = {
  [Symbol.for("_latestValue")]: false
};

const symbol = {
  [Symbol("_latestValue")]: false
};

console.log(
  // This works because the key was created using `Symbol.for`
  symbolFor[Symbol.for("_latestValue")],
  // This does not work
  symbol[Symbol.for("_latestValue")]
);
```

If you have access to the place that *sets* this property, you can expose a reference to the symbol:

```js
const secretKey = Symbol("secretKey");

const myObj = {
  [secretKey]: false
};

console.log(
  myObj[secretKey]
)
```